# Can I connect an external flashlight to an Android smartphone and control it?

Tags: javascript, flashlight

Can I connect an external flashlight to an Android smartphone and control it?

I've seen it done on an iPhone ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iq6Xiums05o&t=04m04s)).
If it's possible, can it be done also via JavaScript?